# Source of background data usage - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I noticed that the app I'm working on has some background data usage, I wanted to investigate the source of this usage, so I used the DevTools, but there were no requests happening while the app was in the background, is there any other way that can help me know the source of this usage?

Comment: Can you please clarify how did you figure out that the app is using data in the background? I think it might be anonymous reporting for flutter and dart, not directly related to your app 

Comment: I'm testing on an Android emulator, in system settings->Apps->My app->Mobile data & WIFI->Background, what is anonymous reporting for flutter and dart, would please provide more info on that matter?